# Creating a NSManagedObjectContext on a private/background queue: how to do?

Tags: multithreading, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am confused about how to create a `MOC` on other threads than the main thread.

On one hand, in [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html), one can read

> A consequence of this is that a context assumes the default owner is
>   the thread or queue that allocated it—this is determined by the thread
>   that calls its init method. You should not, therefore, initialize a
>   context on one thread then pass it to a different thread.

But on the other hand, I have seen code where an auxiliary `MOC` is created the following way, **on the main thread**:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *parentContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

    [parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [parentContext setUndoManager:nil]; // no point in it supporting undo
        [parentContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }];
```

So, what is the good way to create an auxiliary `MOC`? Maybe I should precise that this auxiliary `MOC` is a `@property` of a central class of the project (`AppDelegate` for example).

Comment: They are both true for their relative concurrency types. the first refer to the `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` and the other to `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` (where the context is bound to an execution queue). the docs are quite old, and don't include the "new" queue concurrency type.

Comment: OK, I guess the second way is the best, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs are ambiguous at best.

In my testing, you do not need to use a queue to attach the `NSManagedObjectContext` to its parent or the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

If you are doing a `NSConfinmentConcurrencyType` I set the parent or coordinator on the thread that created it (since that is the thread that can use it).

If you are doing a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` I set the parent or coordinator on the thread that created it as well.  It is the usage of the `NSManagedObjectContext` that is confined or restricted to the private queue.  I define the usage as executing a fetch, deleting an object, etc.  Configuring the `NSManagedObjectContext` is not restricted.

This of course is not in the documentation but the results were produced through testing back when accessing a `NSManagedObjectContext` incorrectly caused an exception.

Comment: Thanks. When you say: "It is the usage of the NSManagedObjectContext that is confined or restricted to the private queue", you mean that you have to use the `performBlock:`, ... methods, doesn't you?

Comment: If you are using a private then yes, a `-performBlock:`. If you are using a confined MOC then no, you should be using it on the thread that created it directly.

Comment: @Marcus-s-zarra Could you update your answers with bits of code (if possible with both cases). It would make a perfect answer! Thanks!